# FireBird 2.5.4.26856 (для Windows (х64)), переключение между библиотеками

Tags: delphi, firebird

У меня есть приложение с  БД, работающее под Windows (х86).
Когда я поставил FireBird 2.5.4.26856 (для Windows (х64)), то, естественно оно не заработало (ошибка невалидности БД).
На одном из сайтов я прочел, что в директории FireBird 2.5.4.26856 (для Windows (х64)), есть две библиотеки «fbclient.dll», следующим по путям:

```
- c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll - версия клиента x64, 

- c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\WOW64\fbclient.dll - версия x32.
```

Возможно, если подключить приложение к правильной библиотеке, а именно к библиотеке из «WOW64\», то приложение заработает **БЕЗ** "*backup/restore*".

Как приложение переключить с библиотеки на библиотеку? А заодно такое сделать и в IBExpert?

Я просмотрел файлы с раширением "*.conf", думал там что-то может быть, но так и не нашел.

Comment: Вы говорите об использовании в _вашей собственной программе_ или _чужой_?

Comment: в чем написано ваше приложение? под какую платформу? .NET? или что-то нативное?

Comment: Да, приложение мое, написано на Delphi

Answer (score 1):

Просто скопируйте библиотеку из `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\WOW64\fbclient.dll` в тот же каталог, где лежит exe-файл вашего приложения.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос "Как приложение переключить с библиотеки на библиотеку?". Самый простой способ использовать нужную DLL - положить ее в тот же каталог что исполняемый файл программы. Какие тут еще нужны развернутые ответы?